# Turtle - Tetris crashes when I use random to select shape from array

Tags: python, crash, turtle-graphics, tetris

I am trying to make Tetris and when I added different shapes of blocks many problems showed up. Biggest of them is that game crashes when you put down 7th block (there is 7 different shapes). Problem is probably in the line where I use random. When I write some number 0-6 instead of random.randint(0, 6) it crashes after first block. Function start is being called every time block gets all the way down.

```
def start():
    global score, blocks1
    penDown.showturtle()
    blocks1 = shapes[random.randint(0, 6)]
    update()
```

Here is whole code:
https://pastebin.com/UdjL5xp5

Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBoPv9sul2E

Comment: What happened when you tried reading the error message?

Comment: "crashes" is not specific enough. Please add the entire traceback to your question.

Comment: Please [try to track down the problem yourself](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) and create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Expecting us to look at hundreds of lines of code off-site is not how Stack Overflow is supposed to work.

Comment: It doesn't show any error. Something like this happen: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBoPv9sul2E